# Remote login to Heroku postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sequelpro

I have a rails app hosted on heroku that uses postgres as the db.

I'd like to manage a few records of the db using a visual db management application, like Sequel Pro.

Sequel Pro needs the credentials of the database to log on (host, username, password, database, port). I do not know what any of these credentials are for my heroku db.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step:

1. Log into Heroku
2. At the top right corner you will see 6 squares next to the Dashboard title. Click this 6 squared icon
3. Click database from the menu that pops up
4. Select the database you want to enter from the list of apps you have.
5. There you should see all the information you need.